# How to add space between key and xlabel?

Tags: gnuplot

```
set xlabel "{/:Italic m} (mag)" 
set key out horiz bot center
```

x-label is too close to the key. How to add space please? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to set the bottom margin:

```
reset session
set multiplot layout 1,2

    set xlabel "{/:Italic m} (mag)" 
    set key out horiz bot center 

    plot sin(x)

    set bmargin 5
    replot 

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Another way instead of changing `bmargin` would be adding an empty line `\n` to the xlabel.

```
set xlabel "{/:Italic m} (mag)\n"
```